# How can I get watir's click to execure javascript href?

Tags: javascript, watir-webdriver

I have a button whose source is

```
<a href="javascript:document.form1.submit()" class="lrg_button" style="float:right">Submit</a>
```

I want to click it, (and wait for the resulting screen to come back).

The code fragment

```
browser.a(:text => "Submit").flash
browser.a(:text => "Submit").click
```

Manages to flash the button, but does not submit the form.

How can I get the javascript in the href executed?

The full form is

```
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="index.php">
<div id="heading" style="display:block; margin:0 auto; text-align:center; width:500; border:1px solid #ccc; width:700px; background:#e8e8e8; margin-top:40px ">
<img src="images/logosymbol.jpg" alt="logo">
<h1 class="loghead" style=" padding:20px 0; margin: 20px 0; color:#243f74">WELCOME TO COACHMASTER</h1>
<table class="login" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="80%"><tbody>
<tr><td>
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tbody>
<tr><td class="logerror" colspan="2">Please enter your credentials</td></tr>
<tr><td class="logprmt">Name:&nbsp;</td>
<td class="logdata"><input name="UserName" size="16" type="text" value=""></td></tr>
<tr><td class="logprmt">Password:&nbsp;</td>
<td class="logdata"><input name="PassWord" size="16" onkeypress="return submitenter(this,event)" type="password"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">
<a href="javascript:document.form1.submit()" class="lrg_button" style="float:right">Submit</a>
</td></tr>    
</tbody></table>
</td></tr> 
</tbody></table>
</form>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Update - the .click command IS sending something to the server. The log includes the "ever-so-helpful" entry

```
IP    [date]  "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
```

If I actually click the button, it sends the correct POST to the correct URL, and does log in as I expect.

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the form?

Comment: What browser are you using? Are your browsers and selenium-webdriver gem up-to-date? It seems to work (ie navigates to index.php) for me when using Firefox/Chrome with selenium-webdriver 2.38.

Answer (score 0):

`document.form1` is returning undefined because you haven't queried the DOM for an element. Change the `href` attribute of the anchor element to something like:

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('form1').submit()" class="lrg_button" style="float:right">Submit</a>
```

And then add an id attribute to the form element

```
<form id="form1" ..>
```

Comment: Before I made this change, the code worked, but Watir failed. After I made this change, neither the code, nor watir submitted the form.

Comment: Could you post the HTML then, please?

Comment: Add an id attribute to the form element `<form id="form1" ..>` then my posted code should work

Comment: It now submits the form in IE but it still fails to submit the form in FF. However IE is totally unusable, because typing into a field is at the super "frozen snail" pace of 8 seconds per character!!!!! Unusable!